# Create same address under ETH as like available in Polygon @gnosis- safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

I initiated a bridge from Polygon network to ETH network for USDT and both have different wallet address under safewallet, so instead of funds getting transfer to ETH address, it went to Same Polygon address but under ETH network, I am not able to access my funds now, I guess we need to create same wallet address under ETH network as like in Polygon, I am non tech person and couldn't replicate the steps provided by Customer support, can you please help.

Polygon Address under Safewallet - matic:0x5dE19F50177599CacaAB0e21D135bC8E805fc363
TRansaction Hash - 0x5eedd77d6d21910233e893cec936e10d8abf51401ff85a345bd70b6fb9fe826b
Safe transaction hash - 0xc4d1a008dd5ff0a87fc15abd56d54dd0f8c5cfb27ac2a54835ce6526510c004a

Can you please create a same wallet address under ETH network as same as Polygon address to access my funds, sorry for inconvenience.

Best Regards
Akash

Comment: Your account is easily recoverable by replaying a transaction on the mainnet. Please get in touch with Safe support for assistance. Do not pay any bounties. It's straightforward. Ping me if you need help.

Comment: The safe was recreated https://app.safe.global/home?safe=eth:0x5dE19F50177599CacaAB0e21D135bC8E805fc363

Answer (score 3):

Brahma Devs have just deployed a Safe on Mainnet, your funds have recovered. You can proceed to take ownership either directly or via https://console.brahma.fi to secure upcoming operations (The team will whitelist you on priority).

Furthermore, to reimburse the gas fee kindly reach out to [@jainargh](https://twitter.com/jainargh) or [@BrahmaFi](https://twitter.com/BrahmaFi) on Twitter.
[image]

Comment: The safe was created with the initial set of owners, they don't need to contact you to take ownership. They can start using it right away.

Comment: Ofcourse, They can use console.brahma.fi to manage multi-chain Safes.

Comment: I know Brahma is a good product, but the way your answer was phrased was misleading, it read like "to access your account, dm me on twitter", just FYI

Comment: Fixed it ser, now its clear.

Answer (score 1):

your safe with the original 2/2 owner setup has already been created. so you can access your funds again. https://app.safe.global/home?safe=eth:0x5dE19F50177599CacaAB0e21D135bC8E805fc363

Comment: seems like there is an indexing issue with assets received before deployment. but they are still in your Safe and only you have access. if you have issues, write a comment here and we can try to help you.